# How I set a OnClick event to <body> element in vaadin 7?

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to "emulate" this:

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = function gameOver() { ...}`

in vaadin 7, to display a dialog box when the user clicks anywhere on the web page

My code:

```
//...
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        Label labelH1 = new Label("<span style=\"color:SteelBlue;\">M</span>atching "
                + "<span style=\"color:Purple;\">G</span>ame!", ContentMode.HTML);
        labelH1.setStyleName("h2");

        Label labelH4 = new Label("Click on the extra smiling face on the <span>left</span>.",
                ContentMode.HTML);
        labelH4.setStyleName("h4");

        CssLayout layout = new CssLayout();
        AbsoluteLayout leftLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        leftLayout.setId("leftSide");

        AbsoluteLayout rightLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
        rightLayout.setId("rightSide");

        layout.addComponent(labelH1);
        layout.addComponent(labelH4);
        layout.addComponent(leftLayout);
        layout.addComponent(rightLayout);

        setContent(layout);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the ClickEvent on your `layout`?

Comment: layout.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutEvents.LayoutClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void layoutClick(LayoutEvents.LayoutClickEvent event) {
                //ACTION
            }
        });

Or a better solution is:
UI.getCurrent().addClickListener(new MouseEvents.ClickListener() { ... })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the click listener on the current UI. As following:

```
UI.getCurrent().addClickListener(new ClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void click(com.vaadin.event.MouseEvents.ClickEvent event)
            {
                // You can show the dialouge box or any other of your desired task here ...!!!
                System.out.println("UI is clicked");

            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this work for me.
I have an image within the UI element, that image has another click event. How do I prevent the `UI.getCurrent.().addClick...(....)` event runs when I click on the image element?

Comment: you can use the click listener for the image and it will override the functionality of the UI clicklistsner. Kindly up-vote and accept the answer if the solution worked for you as it might help the others in the future